# Stop dragging on a force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a force layout in d3 and I have the following code for an item within my node...

```
drag = force.drag()
        .on("dragstart", dragstart);
...
circle = node.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 36)
          .on("dblclick", dblclick)
          .call(drag);
...
node.on("mousedown", function(d){
          if(d == lastNode){
              circle.on(".drag", null);
              drag_line
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("x1", d.x)
                .attr("y1", d.y)
                .attr("x2", d.x)
                .attr("y2", d.y);
          }
          else{
              lastNode = mousedown_node = d;
          }
          svg.call(disabledZoom);

      })
```

The problem is that even when I set the drag to null the circle still drags. Can anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "setting drag to null"? Changing the variable won't change the behaviour, you need to reset the event handler functions for that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking for :) For removing drag behaviour, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136355/d3-js-remove-force-drag-from-a-selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bit confusing but, as you can see in the [Wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#drag) the way to disable drag behaviour is like this...

```
node.on(".drag", null);
//not sure if you have any translations or setting of attributes in 
//your zoom behaviour so maybe this will help also...
node.on(".zoom", null);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me it is what I had originally

Comment: @Jackie if you post a minimum working example exhibiting the behaviour then I'm sure we can solve your problem.

Comment: @Jackie added proper cancellation of zoom behaviour as well in case that is causing drag.

Answer (score 1):

Or you just set a boolean **var** to **false** when you don't want to drag anymore. So you can easily change back to a working drag later on as well. So in your drag function you have:

```
function drag(){
    if (bool){
        //do the dragging stuff
    }
}
```