# Force layout undraggable selection

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I found this solution not compatible with mobile browsers (tried chrome on android and safari on iphone6), I'm not sure about the reason.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13140041/5013297
There is another way to make a selection undraggable?

Comment: The event is probably called `touch.drag` on mobile devices.

Comment: Nop, I just tried. I solved simply applying the drag behaviour to a selection, not all the circles and then remove from selection.
 `d3.selectAll('.drag').call(force.drag)`