# How to remove d3.behavior.drag().on("drag",...) event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, event-handling

I have the following attached to a svg element

```
var dragger = d3.behavior.drag()
.origin(function(d) {
  return d;
})
.on('drag', this.move)
.on('dragend', dropHandler);

//caller
var g = c.append('svg').call(dragger).data([{
x: x0,
y: y0
}]);
```

I am implementing some code inside the dropHandler function that needs it's own implementation of .on("drag",..). **How do I remove the previous event handler from the code?**

I tried the following:

```
.unbind()
selection.on("drag",null);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found an answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136355/d3-js-remove-force-drag-from-a-selection)

```
d3.select('rect#no-drag').on('mousedown.drag', null);
```