# How to entirely remove a d3 forceSimulation and its drag handers

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webcola

I want to allow users to view their network using either a [d3 forceSimulation](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-force-directed-graph) or a [CoLa layout](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/hello-cola), which means when a user fires an event, I need to change out which of those layout algorithms is updating the `x` and `y` attributes of my nodes and edges.

In particular, this requires that I be able to stop the simulations and prevent them from updating those attributes on the data I give them while the other is "active" -- as well as removing the drag handlers associated with them.

My render function currently has:

```
if (use_cola) {

  // MUST TURN OFF D3 AND ITS DRAG HANDLERS!

  force = cola_force.nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(links)
    .groups(groups[group_nodes_by])
    .jaccardLinkLengths(repulsion_strength, 0.7)
    .avoidOverlaps(true)
    .start(50, 0, 50);

  node.call(cola_force.drag);
  group.call(cola_force.drag);

  cola_force.on('tick', ticked);

} else {  // d3

  // MUST TURN OFF COLA AND ITS DRAG HANDLERS!

  force = d3_force.nodes(graph.nodes)
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-repulsion_strength))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2));

  node.call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));  // where those are the conventional functions

  d3_force.on('tick', ticked);
}
```

One solution might be to mangle these objects, e.g. `delete d3_force['something_important']`

Something simpler might work, like `d3_force.nodes([])` or somesuch.

I'm not sure how I would do something similar to the drag handlers because I'm less familiar with how those work.

#### Update 1:

A partial solution suggested for the d3 drag handler (in d3v3) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136355/d3-js-remove-force-drag-from-a-selection):

```
var dragCallback = d3.select('rect#no-drag').property('__onmousedown.drag')['_'];

d3.select('rect#no-drag').on('mousedown.drag', null);
```

and then restoring it later:

```
d3.selectAll('rect#no-drag').on('mousedown.drag', dragCallback);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Stop the simulation if it is still running to prevent it from messing with your nodes coordinates. This can easily be done by calling [`d3_force.stop()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_stop). There is no need to first check if it is running, though, because calling it on an already halted simulation will not hurt either.

   You can later re-activate the simulation by just calling [`d3_force.restart()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_restart) probably pumping some energy back in to heat it up: `d3_force.alpha(1).restart()`.
2. The [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#_drag) tell us how to get rid of the drag behavior:

   > The listeners use the name `.drag`, so you can subsequently unbind the drag behavior as follows:
   >
   > ```
   >  selection.on(".drag", null);
   > ```

   In your case this would be `node.on(".drag", null)`. If the user switches the layout back you can again bind the drag behavior to the `node` selection. For this it might be worth considering to create the drag behavior beforehand and just pass around the reference when rebinding later on.

Comment: This is a great answer! But a partial one. I'm not sure I did a good enough job of specifying above, but I need to figure out how to alternate between these two libraries -- d3 and cola. Your answer shows how to turn off d3 drag handlers and layout so that I can switch to cola, but I still need to figure out how to turn off cola drag handlers and layout to switch to d3. Since cola is rarer and doesn't have great docs, I don't expect you to give me an answer -- but could you point me in the right direction? Where should I go looking for where CoLa binds its drag handlers (analogous to ".drag")?

Comment: @AlexLenail IMO, that‘s rather broad. I understood what you are looking for but, as the question is, I read it as if you were asking for D3 alone. I suggest you keep it to the point and put the Cola part into a new question while providing a link to the other post in both questions. As I am not into Cola myself I‘m afraid that’s the most I can do for you.

Comment: this looks promising, but does `d3_force.stop` exist in v6 and v7? I would assume not?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Why should it not exist? https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_stop

Comment: I am not sure, but my answer seems clearer

Answer (score -1):

There has to be a way to stop a simulation with a reference like so:

```
    let simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes);

    document.turnOffSim = () => {
        simulation.stop(); 
    };
```

yes that seems to work.